# sending image captured phone to a localhost flask server through Volley Multi-part Request ;receiving java.net.socketexception broken pipe error

Tags: android, flask, server, android-volley

I am trying to make an android app that sends an image it captured through the phone to a localhost server running on flask. I am trying to retain the image quality as I will be doing some image processing in the back-end, that's why I am using Volley Multi-part Request. But as I am sending the base64 encoded string of the bitmap as one parameter, I am getting an error from the socket as java.net.socketexception broken pipe.

I have already tried reducing the size of the image, I also tried just sending a string "hi" in the place of the encoded bitmap. When I did this I got a response like "E/Volley: [80295] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500".

```
 public byte[] getFileDataFromDrawable(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    private void uploadBitmap(final Bitmap bitmap) {

        final String tags = "image";
        String url="http://192.168.43.36:5000/recog";
        VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {


            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP);
                params.put("content", imgString);
//                params.put("content","hi");
                return params;
            }


//            @Override
//            protected Map<String, byte[]> getByteData() {
//                Map<String, byte[]> params = new HashMap<>();
//                params.put("content", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap));
//                return params;
//            }
        };


        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(volleyMultipartRequest);
    }
```

The code I am using in the flask file is as follows:-

```
@app.route("/recog", methods=["POST"])
def get_face():

    json1= request.get_json()
    s=json1['content']

    return jsonify(message="Done")
```

I am expecting the base64 to be decoded in the flask file and stored as an image on the local device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I have solved the issue. The issue occurred because I was trying to access the form/multi-part data sent by the client through request.get_json() which is wrong. I instead used werkzeug.datastructures to convert the data into a dictionary and access the required parts.

My current code in flask is as follows:

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict

@app.route("/recog", methods=["POST"])
def get_face():

    data = dict(request.form)
    img=data['content']
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(img)
    filename = 'some_image.jpg'  
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
      f.write(imgdata)
    return jsonify(message="Done")
```

Answer (score 1):

when you print s as per
print(s) what do you have?. It is a series of base64 encoded string

**In python 2.7**

```
import base64
@app.route("/recog", methods=["POST"])
def get_face():

    json1= request.get_json()
    s=json1['content']

    fh = open("imageToSave.png", "wb")
    fh.write(s.decode('base64'))
    fh.close()

    return jsonify(message="Done")
```

**or you can try**

```
import base64
@app.route("/recog", methods=["POST"])
def get_face():

    json1= request.get_json()
    s=json1['content']

    with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
         fh.write(s.decode('base64'))

    return jsonify(message="Done")
```

**For both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x you can also try**

```
import base64
with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
     fh.write(base64.decodebytes(s))
```

**or you can try**

```
with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
     fh.write(base64.decodebytes(s.encode()))
```

**Remember: Always check your code to avoid identation error message**

Comment: Thank you. Using request.get_data() was giving me raw in the form of bytes, then I used werkzeug.datastructures to get my data into dictionary form. Now I am able to access the exact string.

Comment: my answer will also work once you get your image from data dictionary

Comment: Yes, the initial error I was getting was because flask was not able to collect the data sent to it properly.

Comment: so does that mean my solution solved your problem. why dont you accept it as answer

Comment: I asked if anyone knew why I was getting that error and your answer shows the different methods of saving the data into an image. The error was because I was trying to receive the data which was not sent in json format as a json object, because of which I was not receiving any data on my server side. It was solved by using werkzeug data structure to receive data. Sorry to put it bluntly, but your answer was not the solution to the question I asked, I thanked you because you responded.